# Remove columns that contains NA or 0 applied to specific columns

Tags: r, dataframe

So, I'm trying to delete come columns from my dataframe. I want the one filled entirely with NA or 0 to be gone.

I'm using this :

```
tmp <- Filter(function(x)(!all(is.na(x) | (x == "0"))), tmp)
```

This works as expected. My problem is just that I want this function to be applied not on all columns of my df, but on specific ones. I know the column names that I want this function to be applied, so I tried :

```
tmp <- Filter(function(x)(!all(is.na(x) | (x == "0"))) & colnames[x] %in% errornames_c, tmp)
```

but it does not work. I also tried

```
tmp[, 14:ncol(tmp)] <- Filter(function(x)(!all(is.na(x) | (x == "0"))), tmp[, 14:ncol(tmp)])
```

Since I only want this to be applied on column 14 until the last one, but it does not give the expected result either.

I have found several similar posts but without appropriate answers that would suit my need.

So to summarize, I know the names of the columns where I want the function applied while preserving the other ones, and if names are not convenient to use in this case, column 1:14 must be preserved, and 14 to the last one should be targeted. I would prefer to use the entire tmp dataframe instead of splitting it up.

Thanks ahead of time for your help.

Comment: on what condition do you actually want to delete columns? if it has only `NA` or `0` right?

Comment: Correct yes. So a vector c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0) would be deleted, c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0) and c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA) would also be. I just want to ignore the first 14 columns of my dataframe, and I want them untouched in the result. This is where I'm failing to find a solution.

Comment: @homer3018 Based on the comments, the below solution should work

Comment: You can use this `lapply(df[14:ncol(df)], function(x) sum(x, na.rm = T)==0 | all(is.na(x)))
`.

Comment: Thank you all. The below answer from Akrun is doing exactly what I need to do and I do realize now that I should have thought about this trick earlier.... ! 
Thanks again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with

```
cbind(tmp[,1:13], Filter(function(x) !(all(is.na(x)) | all(x == "0")), tmp[, 14:ncol(tmp)] ))
```

#### data

```
tmp <- data.frame(v1 = 0, v2 = c(NA, 1:3), v3 = c(NA, 0, 2, 1),
                v4 = NA, v5 = 1:4, v6= c(NA, NA, NA, 0))
set.seed(24)
tmp <- cbind(as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(13*4), ncol=13)), tmp)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let's assume I want to keep v1 untouched. How would I restrict the filter to apply only on column 2:6 in this case ? This is really what I'm trying to do here. The expected result here would be `data.frame(v1, v2, v3, v5)`

Comment: It is working yes as commented above. Thanks a lot. Should have thought of doing this earlier and not ask but....